# To prove that a multivariable polynomial continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

How to prove that a multivariable polynomial function, say $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ or $g(x,y,z)=x^2+xz^2$ is continuous? Or in simple case, $f$ and $g$ has a limit at a point?

How much preliminaries we need? Does it make use of coordinate projection function? Another question: is $f(x,y,z)=\phi(x)$ continuous, whenever $\phi$ is continuous?If so, it seems OK to discard the usage of coordinate projection functions to this question.

Comment: Hint: A product of continuous functions is continuous. A sum of continuous functions is continuous. The functions $f(x, y, z) = x$, $f(x, y, z) = y$, $f(x, y, z) = z$ are all continuous. Use these rules to show that your functions are continuous.

Comment: @AlexG. Thanks! Is there a more strong theorem that says if $\phi$ is a continuous function of one variable, then $f(x,y,z)=\phi(x)$ is continuous? If so, it seems OK to discard the usage of coordinate projection functions to this question.

Comment: Yes, More Strong Theorem holds because in this case the function $f=\phi\circ\pi$ is continuous as a composition of two continuous functions (here $\pi:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$ is the projection onto the first coordinate).